# Error: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///null

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2636:9)
#1      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2565:48)
#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:89:59)
#3      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:50:14)
#4      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey. (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:503:13)
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("null", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("null", scale: 1.0)

Code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:your_store/widgets/custom_action_bar.dart';
import 'package:your_store/widgets/product_cart.dart';

class HomeTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final CollectionReference _productRef =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: _productRef.get(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                  ),
                );
              }

              // Collection Data ready to display
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                //Display data in List View
                return ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 108.0,
                    bottom: 12.0,
                  ),
                  children:
                  snapshot.data!.docs.map((QueryDocumentSnapshot document) {
                    // Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data();
                    final dynamic data = document.data();

                    return ProductCart(
                      title: data["name"],
                      imageUrl: data["images"[0]],
                      price: "₹${data["price"]}",
                      productId: document.id,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              }

              // Loading State
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          CustomActionBar(
            title: "Home",
            hasBackArrow: false,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably `data["images"[0]]` is having null value which is causing the error.

Comment: could you please check my code and tell me the possible fix? Here is the code link.
https://github.com/Bhaskar2510/Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bhaskar2510 While fetching the product it may be possible that in any product the image link is broken or null so you have to add a null check before passing it to the image widget.

#### Replace below code at [ProductCart](https://github.com/Bhaskar2510/Final/blob/6d46ad67fc94886023b9ed2ff88f522541ed8668/lib/widgets/product_cart.dart#L34)

```dart
Container(
  height: 350.0,
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
    child: Image.network(
      "$imageUrl",
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
    ),
  ),
),
```

#### With

```dart
Container(
  height: 350.0,
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
    child: imageUrl == null ? Placeholder()
     : Image.network(
      "$imageUrl",
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Hey! thanks this resolved my error in code but there is still a problem if you'll try running the code in the emulator and after the login, it's not fetching the products from my ew firebase it's still showing the products from my old linked firebase and showing some crosses.